# Error: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73

Tags: laravel

Cuando ejecuto el comando `php artisan dusk` me sale este error, por lo que no puedo usar **laravel dusk**

> 1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
>   Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException: session not
>   created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73 (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.45.615355
>   (d5698f682d8b2742017df6c81e0bd8e6a3063189),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.6
>   x86_64)

Yo tengo la ultima version de **chrome 77**

**MacOs 10.14.6**

**PHP 7.2.14**

**Laravel 5.6.39**

Parte de mi archivo composer.json es

```
    "require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "laravel/dusk": "^4.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "~2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
    "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay un reporte de bug bastante extenso en el repositorio de GitHub de Dusk: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/641

Ahí se encuentran descritas las soluciones actuales para la mayoría de los casos, siempre y cuando se tenga una versión **reciente** de Dusk.

En el comentario final de dicho hilo (antes de ser bloqueado el 6 de agosto de 2019), se explica:

1. Asegúrese que su versión del navegador Chrome y de ChromeDriver, sean la misma.
2. Si continúan los problemas, utilice temporalmente una versión inferior de Chrome y ChromeDriver.